# Load Kernel module while booting QEMU image through yocto

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, kernel-module

I am trying to build a "Hello World" kernel module using a Yocto recipe, following the setup provided in https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta-skeleton/recipes-kernel/hello-mod. I have successfully built a QEMU image and loaded the module using the `insmod` command.

```
root@192:~# lsmod 
    Not tainted

root@192:~# insmod /lib/modules/5.4.219-yocto-standard/extra/hello.ko 
[   29.599291] hello: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   29.604901] Hello World!

root@192:~# lsmod 
    Tainted: G  
hello 16384 0 - Live 0xd0b1a000 (O)
```

However, I want to automatically load the module when the QEMU image boots up.To achieve this, I made the following modifications to the `hello-mod_0.1.bb` file:

**hello-mod_0.1.bb**

```
SUMMARY = "Example of how to build an external Linux kernel module"
DESCRIPTION = "${SUMMARY}"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=12f884d2ae1ff87c09e5b7ccc2c4ca7e"

inherit module

SRC_URI = "file://Makefile \
           file://hello.c \
           file://COPYING \
          "

S = "${WORKDIR}"
MODULE_NAME = "hello"
# The inherit of module.bbclass will automatically name module packages with
# "kernel-module-" prefix as required by the oe-core build environment.

RPROVIDES:${PN} += "kernel-module-${MODULE_NAME}"

EXTRA_OEMAKE_append_task-install = " -C ${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR} M=${S}"
EXTRA_OEMAKE += "KDIR=${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR}"

KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD_append = "${MODULE_NAME}"
```

With the above changes I created new QEMU image but I can't see the log message while booting the QEMU image.Here are the observations in the QEMU image

```
root@192:~# ls /etc/mo*
/etc/motd

/etc/modules-load.d:
hello.conf


root@192:~# cat /etc/modules-load.d/hello.conf 
hello


root@192:~# find /lib/ -iname "hello.ko"
/lib/modules/5.4.219-yocto-standard/extra/hello.ko

root@192:~# lsmod 
    Not tainted
```

Is there something I missing here to load the kernel module at boot time?

Edit: In this setup systemd is not installed in the QEMU, I need to use some custom binary as init for process.

```
/sbin/init —-> run-mgr
```

Comment: The only thing I see is that your hello.conf  has a .ko ending and usually there is no .ko suffix in this file. See here https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/modules-load.d.html

Comment: @FlorianBerndl, My mistake.I accidentally added the `.ko` in the question.I verified now in the QEMU there is no `.ko` after `hello`. Is there any chance that my yocto is blocking the loading of kernel modules?

Comment: What Yocto branch are you on? Are you mixing syntax between old & new `RPROVIDES:${PN}` and `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD_append` vs `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD:append` [see here](https://wiki.koansoftware.com/index.php/Override_syntax_change_from_Yocto_honister_3.4)

Comment: @ORR, I am using dunfell version is 3.1.I think I am using old yocto version comapre to the link you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`systemd-modules-load.service` is responsible for loading the modules listed in `/etc/modules-load.d` which is how `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD` operates. (See man modules-load.d). Since you replaced `systemd` with a custom `run-mgr`, this service isn't started hence the module is not loaded automatically.

You must edit the custom `run-mgr` to run `/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load` at boot. This is the executable pointed to by `systemd-modules-load.service`.

Comment: apart from using `run-mgr` is there any alternative approach to do this at init phase.

Comment: If you don't want to edit the `run-mgr` configuration at all, one option is to replace /sbin/init with a script that will first run `systemd-modules-load`, then `run-mgr`. This will only work if the system has all required dependencies to run a module ready without `run-mgr`, most notably the filesystem containing the module `.ko`.

Comment: Another possible hook would be to load your module through `udev`. It is very likely that `udev` is started by `run-mgr`. `udev` allows you to write rules calling shell commands and script when a device is detected. You could write such a rule to load your module when any associated piece of hardware is detected. More on this topic: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in